# React-Redux-Firebase App deletes document but doesn't refresh after returning from a details page

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-firebase

I have a react-redux-firebase app that everything works fine at first, I can view, add and delete items and everything works as expected.  However, if I click on a document to see it in more detail on my details page, when I return to the dashboard (home) and delete any document it removes it from database, but doesn't disappear from my app until I refresh the browser.  As long as I don't go to the details page, it works like it's supposed to, automatically refreshing.  Seems leaving my dashboard to go view details on a document then returning takes away the auto-refresh.
Here's a bit of my code:
I map through the docs, adding a link to the detail page for each:

```
<Link to={'/todo/' + e.id} className=""> *bunch of JSX*  </Link>
```

Once I'm on the detail page I connect to the firestore and retrieve the data and display it.  Then if I click on the details it returns me back to the dashboard.
Code on my details page that returns me back:

```
<NavLink to='/'> *bunch of JSX* </NavLink>
```

Thanks for helping,
MB

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna check before rendering your data if the items array is loaded, and display a loader or something while the data is not loaded.

something like this:

```
if (!items) {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Loader />
    </Container>
  );
} else {
  return (
    <Container>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <Item key={item.id} />
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: I mapped through my documents from the database, they display fine, can even delete them fine and they disappear after clicking delete.  But if I don't delete them at first, but instead click on it to take me to another page that shows more info about that document, I return back to my list where everything shows up again, but if I now hit delete on a document it does get deleted from the firebase database, but the web page still shows the deleted document until I refresh the page